# Using Concat Operator ( || ) the Integer Part of is not shown for floating numbers

Tags: sql, oracle

When I am writing a SELECT query in Oracle using concat `||` operator  to concatenate a decimal number and a string. Then for values that have integer part as zero is not shown.

But when I am only selecting Number the Integer part is shown.

**My SQL Query Structure :-**

```
SELECT
NUMBER_VAL ||
STRING_VAL
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

for E.g (selecting only Number):-

```
SELECT 0.1 FROM DUAL;
```

I am getting Result: `0.01`

E.g (Selecting Number and String Concatenated) :-

```
SELECT 0.01 || 'ABCD' FROM DUAL;
```

I am Getting Result: `.01ABCD`

Desired Result: `0.01ABCD`

Can anyone help me how can I achieve the desired result.

---

This is in Addition to Rics Answer .

The Data type of NUMBER_VAL was NUMBER(9,4).

And that's why I had to Use the Format **'99990.9999'**

Comment: Try this `SELECT '0.01' || 'ABCD' FROM DUAL ;`

Comment: @PRDP I mentioned in the SQL Structure that the Number is a column from a table and the Example was to just make the Question more clear.

Comment: Then `cast` the column to `varchar`

Comment: @Prdp - How is `cast` going to help with the OP's problem? The correct answer has already been given and it has nothing to do with `cast`.

Comment: @mathguy - TBH am not a Oracle guy. Just giving my suggestion that is the reason I didn't post answer

Comment: @Prdp - no problem with that in general, but you offered your suggestion after the correct answer had already been posted. If you are not an Oracle guy, trust the Oracle guys and gals (there are a few) to answer Oracle questions!

Comment: And more generally don't rely on implicit type conversion -- it will trip you up eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use to_char function and the appropriate [number format](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm):

```
SELECT
to_char(NUMBER_VAL,'0.99') ||
STRING_VAL
FROM MY_TABLE;
```

Comment: To format your code, select it and press [ctrl]-k or the `{}` symbol in the editing bar. I did that for you here, but remember for the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify format when converting to string, such as:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(0.01, '0.00') || 'ABCD' FROM DUAL;
```